# Inverse of spectrum points of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, inverse

Let $S$ be a complex Banach space and $A$ a bounded linear operator on $S$. Suppose $k_0\in\mathbb{C}$ is a boundary point of the spectrum of $A$.

> How do I show that
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}||(A-k_n)^{-1}||=\infty$$

What I know:
Being a boundary point means that
a) $A-k_0$ is not invertible in $B(S)$
b) there is a sequence $\{k_n\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} k_n=k_0$ and $A-k_n$ is invertible in $B(S)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Further we can use the following fact:
IF $T,T'\in B(S)$, $T$ invertible in $B(S)$ and $||T'-T||\leq\frac{1}{||T^{-1}||}$, THEN $T'$ is invertible in $B(S)$.

How do I use all these?

Comment: Hint: Consider $T'=A-k_0$ and $T=A-k_n$. Is it possible that $T,T'$ admit an estimate as stated?

Comment: @LeBtz What do you mean by estimate?

Comment: The inequality involving $T,T'$.

Comment: @LeBtz I assume that they do not, seeing that $A-k_0$ is not invertible

Comment: Yes, now conclude from that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it is not true that the limit is $\infty$. Then there exists $M>0$ such that for all $N>0$ there exists $n>N$ such that $\|(A-k_n)^{-1}\|<M$.   Let $N$ be such that $|k_0-k_n|<\dfrac1M$ when $n>N$, and then take a particular $n>N$ such that $\|(A-k_n)^{-1}\|<M$.  Then from your "following fact" you will be able to conclude that $(A-k_0)$ is invertible.

Comment: I don't exactly see how $(A-k_0)$ is invertible. So $T=(A-k_0)$ and $T'=(A-k_n)$, but why $||k_0-k_n||<\frac{1}{||(A-k_n)^{-1}||}$?

Comment: $|k_n-k_0|<1/M<1/\|(A-k_n)^{-1}\|$ because of how N and n were chosen, as stated in the third sentence.